# Linear size increase ends up increasing by 1 more sometimes

Tags: c++, windows

I have a flow layout. Inside it I have about 900 tables. Each table is stacked one on top of the other. I have a slider which resizes them and thus causes the flow layout to resize too.

The problem is, the tables should be linearly resizing. Their base size is 200x200. So when scale = 1.0, the w and h of the tables is 200.

Here is an example of the problem:

[image]

My issue is when delta is 8 instead of 9. What could I do to make sure my increases are always linear?

```
void LobbyTableManagaer::changeTableScale( double scale )
    {
        setTableScale(scale);
    }

    void LobbyTableManager::setTableScale( double scale )
    {
        scale += 0.3;
        scale *= 2.0;

        float scrollRel = m_vScroll->getRelativeValue();
        setScale(scale);
        rescaleTables();
        resizeFlow();
    ...

    

    double LobbyTableManager::getTableScale() const
        {
            return (getInnerWidth() / 700.0) * getScale();
        }

    void LobbyFilterManager::valueChanged( agui::Slider* source,int val )
    {
        if(source == m_magnifySlider)
        {
            
            DISPATCH_LOBBY_EVENT
            {
                (*it)->changeTableScale((double)val / source->getRange());
            }
        }
    }
```

In short, I would like to ensure that the tables always increase by a linear amount. I cant understand why every few times delta is 8 rather than 9.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your "200 X Table Scale" values, they are going up by about 8.8.  So when it is rounded to an integer, it will be 9 more than the previous value about 80% of the time and 8 more the other 20% of the time.

If you really need the increases to be the same size every time, you have to do everything with integers.  Otherwise, you have to adjust your scale changes so the result is closer to 9.0.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could do it with integers given that a few other variables depend on the double scale factor?